# Upload documents to task through Workfronts's REST API

Tags: java, rest, attask, workfront-api

We are trying to upload a document to a task consuming REST following below procedure through JAVA

Uploads and Documents
API 2.0 allows users to upload documents through the following API URL:

```
POST /attask/api/upload
```

The API expects the content type to be multipart/form-data. The parameter name for the file must be uploadedFile. The server will return the following JSON data:

```
{
"handle": "4c7c08fa0000002ff924e298ee148df4"
}
```

The handle can then be used when creating an Workfront Document. To create an Workfront Document you will post to to the following URL:

```
        POST /attask/api/document?updates={
             name: aFileName,
             handle: abc...123, (handle from the file upload)
             docObjCode: PROJ, (or TASK, OPTASK, etc)
             objID: abc...123,
             currentVersion:{version:v1.0,fileName:aFileName}
           }
```

Below is the java sample code I am trying to consume rest api for upload

```
 Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 map.put("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
 map.put("name", new File("test.txt"));
 JSONObject handle = client.post("upload", map);
 System.out.println("Handle" + handle.getString("handle") );
```

we are getting filenotfound exception. If anybody implemented file upload to a task in project through JAVA. Can you please share some insight? Thanks in advance

Comment: What does this have to do with Adobe Experience Manager?

Comment: we are trying to call the REST api's from AEM...anyway not much related though..we use Emberjs for front end and we are calling the servlet from ember and consuming the REST.